# How to make browsers download file with multiple threads

Tags: google-chrome, http, internet-explorer

I have a scenario where a large file needs to be send for download. I am trying to see what can be done on the browser side to enable faster download.

From server side, I can tell the browser that I support ranges and sending partial content (`HTTP 206` with `Content-Range` and `Content-Length`) but that will not help unless the browser can make parallel requests for different ranges.

Is there a way to configure browsers to do this ? I did not see anything in chrome or IE for this.

Comment: Why would it be faster to use multiple threads if the limiting factor is the bandwidth?

Comment: nope even browsers themselves have no control over downloading if a downloader extension is installed.